# What is the transition matrix and stationary distribution of ${T}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $T = (X_n:n \in \mathbb{N})$ denote a homogeneous Markov chain with state space $E=\lbrace 1, 2, 3\rbrace$ and
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=2\vert X_0=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1=3\vert X_0=1)=\frac{1}{3}$$
as well as
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=1\vert X_0=2) = \mathbb{P}(X_1=2\vert X_0=3)=1.$$

I suspect that the transition matrix is
$$T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right).$$

Also, I understand that the stationary distribution is a limiting form of the Markov chain, and so from the definition of a stationary distribution we find it $\pi$, the stationary distribution, by calculating $\pi=\pi T$.

We calculate the stationary distribution by finding left eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $1$. So,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3}\pi_1 +\frac{1}{3}\pi_2+\frac{1}{3}\pi_3 & =\pi_1,\\
\pi_1 & =\pi_2  \hspace{1.0cm}\textrm{and}\\
\pi_2 & =\pi_3.
\end{align*}
So $\pi_1=\pi_2=\pi_3$ and as $\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=1$, then $$\pi=\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}\right).$$

Is this correct?

Also, positive recurrent Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution. How do I determine if this Markov chain is positive recurrent, and thus if the above stationary distribution is unique?

Comment: Transition matrices have row-sum 1 or column-sum 1, depending on the convention. Yours has neither. Re the stationary distribution, surely you know how to compute it starting from the transition matrix?

Comment: You're right and I have amended the transition matrix. Hopefully it is now correct?

Comment: I'm still unsure of how to derive the stationary distribution. Any help on how to start it would be great. Thank you

Comment: One might want to start from the definition, so, what is the definition of a stationary distribution for the transition matrix T?

Comment: Definition is as follows: Let T denote a Markov chain with state space $E$ and $\pi$ a measure on $E$. If $\mathbb{P}(X_n=i)=\mathbb{P}(X_0=i)=\pi_i$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i \in E$, then $T^\pi$ is called stationary and $\pi$ is a stationary measure for $T$. And if $\pi$ is a probability measure, then it is called the stationary distribution for $T$.

Comment: Then what does it mean in terms of $(T,\pi)$ to assume that $X_0$ and $X_1$ both have distribution $\pi$?

Comment: Would it mean that $\pi=\pi P$? I've read that all finite Markov chains have a stationary distribution. But some have more than one. And we can find the stationary distribution by finding left eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, so in your case, $\pi T=\pi$.

Comment: I've edited the question to better reflect my understanding and to make everything more clear for others, please take a look.

Comment: For the answer you give, $\pi T\ne\pi$, so something must be wrong. The system of three equations you have written down give the solution of $T\pi=\pi$, which is a different kettle of fish altogether.

Comment: Oh, so from my working out, where did I go wrong?

Comment: As I wrote, you wanted the three equations for the system $\pi T=\pi$, but you wrote down the three equations for the system $T\pi=\pi$.

Comment: Ok, thank you that makes much more sense. Does this Markov chain have a unique stationary distribution? Or are there more than one? I know that a positive recurrent Markov chain has a unique distribution but I am not sure how to check if this Markov chain is positive recurrent. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> Does this Markov chain have a unique stationary distribution? Or are there more than one? I know that a positive recurrent Markov chain has a unique distribution but I am not sure how to check if this Markov chain is positive recurrent.

The chain is irreducible on a finite state space hence it is positive recurrent and has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$.
Following the precise indications in the comments, one gets that $\pi$ is in the proportions 3:2:1, thus $\pi=(\frac12,\frac13,\frac16)$.